# Change URL or internal page using jQuery Mobile select as menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm using a select box as a menu nav for my jQuery Mobile site.

Some items of the menu link to internal pages and others to external URLs.

I'm using the following to code to change page url:

```
$('#menu-select').change(function() {
   window.location = $(this).data('location')  
})
```

The HTML:

```
 <select name='select-choice-1' id="menu-select">
    <option value="">Menú:</option>
    <option value="index.php">Noticias</option>
    <option value="index.php#tramites" data-location='index.php#tramites'>Trámites</option>
    <option value="index.php#twitter" data-location='index.php#twitter'>Twitter</option>
    <option value="virgen_del_valle.php">Parque Virgen del Valle</option>
    </select>
```

I have three pages:

- index.php (with contain to pages or data-role="page" with and id)
- news.php
- event.php

The problem is that when I select, for example, Home option, then More Information and tried to go to Event, it didn't load the page.

It's inconsistent with external and internal url loading.

I think this code must have a conditional for internal pages and for external url.

Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Use [$.mobile.changePage()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

Comment: I agree with omar, quick question though does $(this).attr('data-location') have any more luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#menu-select').change(function () {
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: `data-location` is not set for half of the options. `value` is semantic and consistently set for all options.